# Syntax for default template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, nested, default, allocator

I have written a list-like template class sll (Single Linked List). Now, I am trying to plugin an allocator to it. I have the default allocator, allocator, and a pool based allocator, pool_allocator. These are designed after STL allocator interface, but I need to add the number of elements that the allocator would handle (the max_size) as a template parameter. So, I have done the following.

```
enum  {Default_1 = 16};         // for example
template <typename T, size_t N = Default_1>
struct allocator {
};

enum  {Default_2 = 32};         // for example
template <typename T, size_t N = Default_2>
struct pool_allocator {
};
```

I want to support two kinds if usage by the client:

```
1. sll<int>  == implying ==> sll<int, allocator<int, Default_1> >

2. sll<int, pool_allocator<int, 4096> >
```

The difficulty I am having is specifying the default allocator in the sll template class. Initially I had

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = allocator<T> > class sll { ...};
```

It works, but the problem is, user can;t specify the capacity of the allocator.

I tried

```
template<typename T, 
    typename Allocator = allocator< typename T, size_t N = Default_3> >
class sll { ... };
```

but I receive the error:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

I tried few other combinations, but none of them worked. At this point, I am out of ideas, and looking for help from the SO community. Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write:

```
template<typename T, 
    typename Allocator = allocator<T, Default_3> >
class sll { ... };
```

Comment: +1: Thank you. That was simple, I overlooked the most simple option :-(. A follow up question is: Inside sll class template, how do I access the second template argument of the Allocator (note uppercase A)?

Comment: You can define static constant inside the allocator class, for example `enum{ size = ...; }`. So you can access to it as `Allocator::size`. But you have to define the `size` constant inside all allocator. Or you can use traits.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about the static const approach.